# CSS animation On ReactJS Project Unable to make it work

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Im new to React, Im trying to make my background animated on my home section but apparently the animation on the linear-gradient background does not work. Any help is appreciated.;)

```
const gradient = keyframes` //ANIMATION
0% {
  background-position: 0% 50%;
}
50% {
  background-position: 100% 50%;
}
100% {
  background-position: 0% 50%;
}
`

const Section = styled.section ` 
// min-height: ${props => `calc(100vh ${props.theme.navHeight})` };
width: 100vw;
position: relative;
// background-color: ${props => props.theme.body};
animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #000, #211725, #2f0a3d, #6f1e8e); //LINEAR
animation: ${gradient} 15s ease infinite; //ANIMATION
`
```

What I have imported :

```
import React from 'react'
import TypeWriterText from '../TypeWriterText'
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components'
import CoverVideo from '../CoverVideo'
import RoundTextBlack from '../../assets/Rounded-Text-White.png';
```

Comment: What do you want the animation to do (as the linear background is filling the element currently). How is it to move, if it goes down what comes in above it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing background-size

```
    const Section = styled.section ` 
      // min-height: ${props => `calc(100vh ${props.theme.navHeight})` };
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh
      position: relative;
      // background-color: ${props => props.theme.body};
      // this line might be for nothing  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
      background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #000, #211725, #2f0a3d, #6f1e8e);   //LINEAR   
      background-size: 500% 500%;

      animation: ${gradient} 15s ease infinite; //ANIMATION
    `
```

Here is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-5lcm5v?file=/index.js